# How to close all applications in a workspace?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, workspaces

Is there a gnome 3 extension or a fedora 25 shortcut to close all  opened applications in a workspace? (Closing the workspace itself by pressing an X for example).

I've seen that functionality somewhere long time ago, forgot where, but it's not available in fedora by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer below was written and tested on Gnome3 / Ubuntu. Please mention if you run into issues when running it on Fedora / Gnome.

---

#### Script to close all application windows on a specific workspace in Gnome

The script below will close all windows on a specific workspace, with two options:

1. When run *without* arguments, it closes all windows on the *current* workspace, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/script.py
   ```
2. when run with a specific workspace as argument, it will close all windows on that workspace, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/script.py 0
   ```

   will close all applications on workspace 1. ***Note that the first workspace has index 0***

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1:]

def check_close(w_id):
    w_data = get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])
    if "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in w_data:
        subprocess.call(["wmctrl", "-ic", w])

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")

wlist = [l.split() for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).splitlines()]

arg = arg[0] if arg else [
    l.split()[0] for l in get(["wmctrl", "-d"]).splitlines() if '*' in l
    ][0]

for w in [w[0] for w in wlist if w[1] == arg]:
    check_close(w)
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl), which should be installed if it isn't on your system.
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `close_wins.py`
3. Now test- rune the script from a terminal window, with the targeted workspace as argument, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/close_wins.py 2
   ```

   to gracefully close all windows *on workspace 3* (0 = worspace 1)

   To close all windows on *the current workspace*, run it without arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/close_wins.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/close_wins.py
   ```

...or run it in any other way you'd prefer.

#### Explanation

The command `wmctrl -lG`  will give us information on the currently opened windows. The output looks like:

```
0x018000f9  0 135  206  650  500  jacob-System-Product-Name pscript_6.py (1,6 GB Volume /media/jacob/6C08-F637) - gedit
0x01600a09  1 283  275  724  443  jacob-System-Product-Name jacob@jacob-System-Product-Name: ~
0x018018be  1 152  407  650  500  jacob-System-Product-Name Untitled Document 1 - gedit
0x0140008c  2 0    101  1280 960  jacob-System-Product-Name gnome - Can I have a countdown window show the time until next suspend? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x01600a49  2 47   146  724  443  jacob-System-Product-Name jacob@jacob-System-Product-Name: ~
```

From the second column, we can retrieve the window's location:

```
0x0140008c  2 0    101  1280 960  jacob-System-Product-Name gnome - Can I have a countdown window show the time until next suspend? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
```

The `2` means the window is on workspace 3, since `0` refers to the first workspace.

***If the script runs with the workspace as argument***, the script parses out the corresponding window- id's and subsequently closes them gracefully with the command (e.g.):

```
wmctrl -ic 0x0140008c
```

***If the script runs without the workspace as argument***, the script retrieves the current workspace from the command:

```
wmctrl -d
```

and subsequently uses the current workspace internally as argument.

Comment: Note that this will not work in a Wayland session.

Comment: @mattdm Not sure what OP is using, but isn't gnome on X?

Comment: In Fedora 25, the default GNOME session is on Wayland with X as a fallback.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It works great, thank you so much

Comment: @mattdm I'm using wayland and it does work `loginctl show-session 1 -p Type` outputs `Type=wayland`

Comment: @Lynob Thanks for mentioning! Glad it works :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm what doesnt work is passing parameters, so `script.py 2` doesn't close apps in the second workplace, but I don't need that, I'm happy to close all apps in the current workspace, that's all I need

Comment: @Lynob Thanks! could you post (on e.g. pastebin) the output of `wmctrl -lG`? It should be relatively easy to adapt using the args to wayland.

Comment: @JacobVlijm no no it works great! the current workspace is 0 not 1, the second is 1, so if I want to close the second workspace, I do `script.py 1` I just noticed that after reading the output of `wmctrl -lG`

Comment: Ah, greatgreat :) @Lynob

Comment: Note that if an application is minimized in tray, the script won't close it, which is exactly what I want, if someone wants to close the apps in tray he might have to edit the script, personally I find it perfect and I don't want to close apps in tray

Comment: @Lynob Aha, thanks for the feedback! Can be fixed. I will make it an option in the script. :)

Comment: There's one problem: unsaved documents show a dialog box asking for saving, but clicking cancel closes the window without saving

Comment: @DanielAlder the language is python, not so much Perl :)